# Cleanup console command on any termination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have the following (simple) lock code for a Laravel 5.3 command:

```
private $hash = null;
public final function handle() {
    try { 
        $this->hash = md5(serialize([ static::class, $this->arguments(), $this->options() ]));
        $this->info("Generated signature ".$this->hash,"v");

        if (Redis::exists($this->hash)) {
            $this->hash = null;
            throw new \Exception("Method ".$this->signature." is already running");
        }            
        Redis::set($this->hash, true);                                    
        $this->info("Running method","vv");
        $this->runMutuallyExclusiveCommand(); //Actual command is not important here
        $this->cleanup();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->error($e->getMessage());
    } 
}

public function cleanup() {
    if (is_string($this->hash)) {
        Redis::del($this->hash);
    }
}
```

This works fine if the command is allowed to go through its execution cycle normally (including handling when there's a PHP exception). However the problem arises when the command is interrupted via other means (e.g. CTRL-C or when the terminal window is closed). In that case the cleanup code is not ran and the command is considered to be still "executing" so I need to manually remove the entry from the cache in order to restart it. I have tried running the `cleanup` code in a `__destruct` function but that does not seem to be called either.

My question is, is there a way to set some code to be ran when a command is terminated regardless how it was terminated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. When you kill the running process, either by Ctrl-C or just closing the terminal, you terminate it. You would need to have an interrupt in your shell that links to your cleanup code, but that is way out of scope.

There are other options however. Cron jobs can be run at intermittent intervals to perform clean up tasks and other helpful things. You could also create a start up routine that runs prior to your current code. When you execute the start up routine, it could do the cleanup for you, then call your current routine. I believe your best bet is to use a cron job that simply runs at given intervals that then looks for entries in the cache that are no longer appropriate, and then cleans them. Here is a decent site to get you started with cron jobs https://www.linux.com/learn/scheduling-magic-intro-cron-linux

Comment: I don't think that a cron is appropriate because I can't know whether the cache entry is there because the task was killed or because the task is still running. But I am willing to concede that the answer is indeed no.